# CryptoNight Miner in Python?

Tags: mining

Is there a Crypto Night Miner in Python?

If not, Please Write one, with pool support.

Reward: 0.1 XMR;

Thanks A Million!

Comment: 0.1 XMR != A Million

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SE is not the appropriate place to advertise a bounty of this type.

Answer (score 1):

No, and no, respectively.

A python miner would likely be pretty slow. At a push, you could maybe use a python main calling C code for the crypto parts.

Comment: I understand that a python miner will be extremely slow, however, I have a specific use for the same. I have about 50 computer where I can execute only python. I have to pay no cost to operate those computers either. I  think I can make a little money of it.